# Indexing dynamic collections in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In my node app, I am saving data in to dynamic mongodb collections and those collections are named after a value in the data.

Sample code:

```
function saveToDb(data){

    let collectionName = data.someType;
    let collection = getCollection(collectionName);

    return collection.save(data);
}
```

Please note that I do not know the collection name upfront, and the collections are being created as and when the corresponding data come for the first time.

If i want to index a few known fields in this document, I am thinking of  calling ***collection.createIndex()*** after every save. But, will it hit the performance too much? Or any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally went ahead with calling `collection.createIndex()` after every save. Monitoring it for a few weeks now and finding no performance problem identified with ~25K records.

Note: This doesnt mean calling `collection.createIndex()` after every save is the ideal solution. If someone has a better one, please feel free to comment.